# String replacement using sub function

Tags: r, regex

I am attempting to extract the names of NBA players from a column in a database. However, the format of the the names in the names column is the following:

"LeBron James\\jamesle01"

I used the following regex expression inside a sub function to attempt to keep only the name portion:

```
sub("([A-Z]\\w+\\s*-*'*[a-z]*\\s*\\.*|[A-Z]\\.\\s*)\\*\\*[a-z]*\\d*\\d*", replacement = "\\1", x = nba_salaries$Names)
```

The expression is meant to take into account for unusual names that contain more than just alphanumeric characters (e.g. Michael Kidd-Gilchrist, De'Andre Jordan, Luc Mbah a Moute, etc.)

However, when I run the following,

```
head(nba_salaries$Names)
```

The names end up being in the same format.

I have used regexr.com to ensure that the regex expression captures the strings properly.

Comment: Not familiar with R but couldn't you just search for the \\ in the names and split the names on that?

Comment: It is not clear: 1) Do all strings follow the format `Name\\username`? 2) Is it not easier to split with ``\\`` then and get the 0th index element? Or just take all before the ``\\` with `sub("^(.*?)\\\\.*", "\\1", s)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, all names follow that format. My solution is probably very inefficient so you are probably right. I will look into your method.

Comment: I guess rosscova has already posted a working solution. I'd use a fixed string though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also be aware that in the R language, the first element is `1`, not `0`.

Comment: @rosscova: Glad you keep vigil :) I am sleeping in front of the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, you can split the text by the "\\" string, and then take only the first element:

```
text <- c( "LeBron James\\jamesle01", "Michael Jordan\\jamesle01" )

sapply( strsplit( text, "\\\\" ), "[", 1 )
```

Which gives

```
[1] "LeBron James"   "Michael Jordan"
```

To explain. The "[" is a function*, which is being called within `sapply`. So we pass the result of `strsplit` as the `X` in `sapply`, and apply the `[` function to it* with the parameter `1` to take the 1st element. Here's another way to put it:

```
text <- strsplit( text, "\\\\" )
```

This will output a list, with each list element containing a vector, where the first element is the text before the "\\" string, and the second element contains any text after it. Then we use the "[" function*, passing the parameter `1`, to take the first element of each of those vectors:

```
text <- sapply( X = text, FUN = "[", 1 )
```

Edit to add, I personally like using the `magrittr` pipe for things like this, just to make it a little more readable:

```
library( magrittr )

text <- strsplit( x = text, split = "\\\\" ) %>%
    sapply( FUN = "[", 1 )
```

- the "[" function is the function called when you subset with `[]`. eg: `vector[1:3]` or in this case `vector[1]` (thanks @MathewLundberg for the suggestion here)

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, what is the purpose for the "[" and 1 parameters you passed into sapply?